# Webpack tries to copy files before compiling while I'm expecting the opposit

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I want the copy plugin to be executed after compilation which is logical. Unfortunately, I needed to compile using web-pack twice each time to have the fresh version on production; Until I figured out that it is copying files first then compiling new version (all logical, but my slow thinking didn't pay attention).

Here is the script:

```
const path = require("path");
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

const paths = {
  dist: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
  public: path.resolve(__dirname, "..", "public", "javascripts"),
};
const isDevEnv = process.argv.includes("-w");
const devConfig = {
  mode: "development",
  devtool: "eval-source-map",
};
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: "./src/main.js",
    skills: "./src/views/skills/skills.js",
    listing: "./src/views/listings/listing.js",
  },
  output: {
    filename: "[name].js",
    path: paths.dist,
  },
  ...(isDevEnv && devConfig),
  plugins: [
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [{ from: "dist", to: paths.public, noErrorOnMissing: true }],
    }),
    new Dotenv()
  ],
};
```

Comment: * ℹ️ copy-webpack-plugin is not designed to copy files generated from the build process; rather, it is to copy files that already exist in the source tree, as part of the build process.*

[source](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin/)

Comment: true, I didn't pay attention

Comment: You can easily make a script that runs `webpack` and then `cp` every file needed.

Comment: yes, I'm thinking of this and trying 'filemanager-webpack-plugin'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by @MinusFour, `copy-webpack-plugin` is not designed to copy files generated from the build process.

I used *filemanager-webpack-plugin* with `copy` and `onEnd` event.

```
new FileManagerPlugin({
  events: {
    onStart: {},
    onEnd: {
      copy: [{ source: "dist", destination: paths.public }],
    },
  },
  runTasksInSeries: false,
  runOnceInWatchMode: false,
}),
```